# Hide child grid on Pivot selected Item change UWP

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

My Code is like this

```
<Grid  Width="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
    <Pivot x:Name="mainContentPivot"  SelectionChanged="mainContentPivot_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{x:Bind viewModel.headerElement, Mode=OneWay}" >

        <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:UIModel">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Name="grd" >
                    <local1:myusercontrol></local1:myusercontrol>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>

        </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </Pivot>

</Grid>
```

When a Pivot item is clicked I want the Grid (Grid inside Pivot) to be hidden.

```
   public MyViewPage()
    {
        DataContext = viewModel;
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void mainContentPivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PivotItem item = (sender as Pivot).ContainerFromItem((sender as Pivot).SelectedItem) as PivotItem;
        var gridView = FindElementInVisualTree<Grid>(item);
        gridView.Visibility=Visibility.Collapsed;

    }

    private T FindElementInVisualTree<T>(DependencyObject parentElement) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parentElement);
        if (count == 0) return null;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parentElement, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
                return (T)child;
            else
            {
                var result = FindElementInVisualTree<T>(child);
                if (result != null)
                    return result;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

All looks good to me, But when pivot selected Item is changed, Gris is not going hidden. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Grid you got by using the method `var gridView = FindElementInVisualTree<Grid>(item);` is not the root element which names 'grd' of the data template, so it caused the unexpected behavior. If you still want to traverse visual tree to get the Grid, you can try to use the following method.

```
PivotItem item = (sender as Pivot).ContainerFromItem((sender as Pivot).SelectedItem) as PivotItem;
var itemsGrid = item.ContentTemplateRoot as Grid;
itemsGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

However, generally we recommend you can use the binding to achieve it. You can define a property which represents visibility in your UIModel to bind with the Visibility of Grid. When you select the item, change the proeprty to Collapsed.

.xaml:

```
<Pivot x:Name="mainContentPivot"  SelectionChanged="mainContentPivot_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{x:Bind viewModel.headerElement, Mode=OneWay}" >
    ......
    <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Name="grd" Visibility="{Binding isVisual}">
                <local:myusercontrol></local:myusercontrol>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</Pivot>
```

.cs:

```
public class UIModel 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Visibility isVisual { get; set; }
}

private void mainContentPivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    PivotItem item = (sender as Pivot).ContainerFromItem((sender as Pivot).SelectedItem) as PivotItem;
    (item.DataContext as UIModel).isVisual = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```